# The 4 columns consist of a table, I want to retrieve the rows which are published within 2 hours, how can I implement it with css selector or xpath?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

```
<el-table-column width="100" prop="secCode" sortable="custom" label="代码">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                    <a class="ahover" target="_blank" :href="'/new'+ '/disclosure/stock?stockCode=' + scope.row.secCode + '&orgId=' + scope.row.orgId">
                                        <span class="code">{{scope.row.secCode}}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                            <el-table-column width="180" prop="secName" label="简称">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                    <a class="ahover" target="_blank" :href="'/new'+ '/disclosure/stock?stockCode=' + scope.row.secCode + '&orgId=' + scope.row.orgId">
                                        <span :title="scope.row.secName" class="code delete-hl" v-html="scope.row.secName.length>8?scope.row.secName.slice(0,8)+'...':scope.row.secName"></span>
                                    </a>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                            <el-table-column prop="announcementTitle" label="公告标题">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                <span class="ahover">
                                    <a v-html="scope.row.announcementTitle" target="_blank" :href="linkLastPage(scope.row)"></a>
                                    <span v-show="checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)" class="icon-f"><i class="iconfont" :class="[checkDocType(scope.row.adjunctType)]"></i></span>
                                </span>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
                            <el-table-column width="150" align="left" prop="announcementTime" sortable="custom" label="公告时间">
                                <template slot-scope="scope">
                                    <span class="date">{{fomatDate(scope.row.announcementTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')}}</span>
                                </template>
                            </el-table-column>
```

There are 4 columns, they are secCode,secName,announcementTitle,announcementTime, the 4 columns consist of a table, I want to retrieve the rows which are published within 2 hours, how can I implement it with css selector or xpath?